# Is there any other validation metrics for trainer?

Tags: allennlp

I use the seq2seq model and it can compute BLEU score (a NMT score) every epoch. However, I cannot set BLEU score as validation metric so it cannot early stop in training. I read the source code, but there are no hints as to what kind of string could be added to the validation metrics except for "+loss". Please save me, thanks!

Comment: I tried "+bleu", but it failed without logging available metric str.

Answer (score 2):

The default `validation_metric` is actually `"-loss"`, not `"+loss"`. The "-" means this is a metric that should be minimized, not maximized.

So to use BLEU score instead, set the `validation_metric` to `"+BLEU"`.

In general, you can use any metric that's returned by your model's [`.get_metric()`](https://docs.allennlp.org/v1.2.0rc1/api/models/model/#get_metrics) method. The name of the metric you use for `validation_metric` just has to match the corresponding key from the dictionary returned by `.get_metric()`.

In your case, presumably your model's `.get_metric()` method returns something like this: `{"BLEU": ...}`, which is why `validation_metric` should be set to `"+BLEU"`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It solve my problem! Since my problem is why "BLEU" instead of "bleu" (i.e., how the str is related to paticular metric), I have two suggestions to the document: It would be better if it is commented to the parameter "validation metric", or log the available metric of "validation_metric". It would very helpful for the green-hand just like me, as I read and search the available "metric str" by reading source code for two hours but failed :)

Comment: @qiuyuan, would you be interested in making a PR to improve the documentation on this?

Comment: Of course, I will have a try and add some complementary documentation recently :)